# how to restrict user a window to the file uploads to S3 in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am studying AWS, one of the scenario I came across in a practice exam is below and I doubt the given answer is correct or incorrect:

> A company is building a mobile social media management solution and
>   uses S3 as their data store. The company wants to allow newly
>   registered users to upload their profile picture within a week after
>   registration is completed. How can they handle the uploads in a
>   simplest way?

```
Options:
A. Use Pre-Signed URLs instead to upload the pictures
B. Generate a custome application URL for each user with a validity of 1 week
C. Provide User IAM Role access to the S3 bucket
D. Control it through the S3 bucket policy
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which of those four is the "given answer" that you're doubting?

Comment: The answer says A, but I don't see how the `within a week` is addressed in the A

Comment: within a week is not a building time, it is just limitation for the access, like a due date. Pre-signed url can set the expiry date for a week.

Comment: @mdivk You can set an expiration on pre-signed URLs. Set it to a week and it won't work after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a signed url for S3 and give it to someone, you are giving them access to upload a document to that path in your S3 bucket. You can set the “expires-in” property to a max of 604800 seconds (one week). This way the user will be able to upload the file to that path in that bucket and then after one week they will lose access.

Comment: Thanks. what is the difference of B? can B meets the requirement?

Comment: You can implement this functionality yourself in your application, but the question asks for the simplest way. Making application specific URL’s would be quite a task since you need to implement managing permissions, generating the urls, giving those url credentials the correct access rights, and then managing expiration.